# JSON response for login script with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have the following login script.

```
<?php

include("connect.php");
include("functions.php"); 
$error = "";

$j = new stdClass();
$j->status  = "success";
$j->message = "Logged In";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);

    if(email_exists($email,$con)){
        $error = "Email Exists";

        echo json_encode($j);
    }else{
        $error = "Email does not exist";


    }

}
```

?>

The functions.php file is.

```
<?php
function  email_exists($email,$con){


    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

?>

What I am doing is selecting the ids from the database and check if the email exists with the

```
mysqli_num_rows(query)
```

function. If it returns one or true then email exists so the user can log in. If not meaning we return 0 or false then email does not exist,and hence the user can not log in.

I want to return for each case a JSON response. For example if user's email is found then.

```
{
  "status":"success"
  "message:"You are now logged in"
}
```

When the user's email is not found then,

```
{
  "status":"fail"
  "message:"email not found"
}
```

Any ideas? I created the following variable but only for the success case. I want the same variable to be changed to fail when no email is found

```
$j = new stdClass();
$j->status  = "success";
$j->message = "Logged In";
```

Thanks.

Comment: you have json_encode an array and not an object, the function is the one creating the object to send in the client side

Comment: Why? It also works with object ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
$qry ='SELECT * FROM `registration` WHERE `email`="'.$email.'" && `password`="'.$password.'"';
$login = mysqli_query($con, $qry) or die (mysqli_error());
$no_of_row=mysqli_num_rows($login);
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login);       
    if($no_of_row==1)
{
    $response["error"] = 0;
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["email"] = $email;
    $response["message"] = "You Logged In Successfully";


 }
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: This was the solution for you? But how? :D

Answer (score 1):

And what is the problem? :)

Maybe:

```
if(!email_exists($email,$con)){
    $j->status  = "fail";
    $j->message = "Email does not exist";

}

echo json_encode($j);
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer.

```
if(email_exists($email,$con)){
        $error = "Email Exists";
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Logged in'));


    }else{
        $error = "Email does not exist";
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'fail', 'message' => 'Email not found'));

    }
```

I can not think of anything else at the moment.